# Angular2: Error binding observable array to component

Tags: angular, observable, ngfor

I'm trying to display a list of `Contact`s in a list:

```
<h1>Contacts</h1>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts$ | async">
        <ul>
            <h1>Name: {{contact.name}}</h1>
            <li>ObjectID: {{contact._id}}</li>
            <li>LastName: {{contact.lastName}}</li>
            <li>FirstName: {{contact.firstName}}</li>
            <li>Email: {{contact.email}}</li>
            <li>Notes:
                <ul *ngFor="let note of contact.notes">
                    <li>{{note}}</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`contacts$` is an `Observable<Array<Object>>`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'contacts-list',
    templateUrl: 'list.component.html'
})
export class ContactsListComponent implements OnInit {
    contacts$: Observable<Array<Object>>;


    constructor(private logger: LoggerService,
                private router: Router,
                private trackerService: TrackerService) {
        this.logger.debug(`ContactListComponent.ctor`);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.contacts$ = this.trackerService.cache('tracker/contacts');
    }
}
```

For now, `TrackerService.cache(...)` is simply creating an `Observable` froma hardcoded array, for testing:

```
public cache(path: string): Observable<Array<Object>> {
    let retval = [new Object({
        _id: '123abc',
        lastName: 'last',
        firstName: 'first',
        email: 'someone@example.com',
        notes: ['note 1', 'note 2']
    }), new Object({
        _id: '123abc',
        lastName: 'last',
        firstName: 'first',
        email: 'someone@example.com',
        notes: ['note 1', 'note 2']
    })];
    return Observable.from(retval)
        .map((v) => {
            this.logger.debug(`Mapping value: ${JSON.stringify(v)}`);
            return v;
        });
}
```

The `.map()` operation is just for testing, and I see this in the chrome console:

```
debug DEBUG: Mapping value: {"_id":"123abc","lastName":"last","firstName":"first","email":"someone@example.com","notes":["note 1","note 2"]}
```

However when I run this, I'm getting:

> Error: Error in ./ContactsListComponent class ContactsListComponent -
>   inline template:2:8 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object
>   '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
>   Iterables such as Arrays.

I've read other SO threads, angular.io, and my ng2-book which has similar examples, but I'm just not figuring this out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so do you get desire data in console?

Comment: this.contacts$.subscribe(value => this.contact = value); after this.contacts$ = this.trackerService.cache('tracker/contacts'); and in *ngFor replace contacts$ | async with  contact. declare a contact: any . you need to subscribe to observable

Comment: @AmitSuhag: I thought the async pipe handled the subscription for me? Isn't that the whole point of the async pipe?

Comment: @micronyks: I see the output to the debug log from the `map` call, but I do the template is not rendered.

Comment: I dont thing that you are getting array in result. its just a json object that your are getting. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.from` will emit **each** element of the array.

Use `Observable.of` to emit the **whole** array.

Comment: That was the problem.  @micronyks' comment led me to the solution as well, and I was just about to post an answer.

Comment: I guess that raises a question, however.  In my original code where I was using `from`, my `.map()` function was only being hit once, for one element of the array.  If `from` emits each element of the array, why did I only see one in my debug output?

Comment: Hm, that's strange indeed. You should see two logs. A possibility is that, since your two objects are equals, the log generated is the same. In such case, chrome console just print the log once, but adds a count on the left of the printed log. In your case you could see something like `(2) Mapping value .... `